# android intent give NullPointerException in gridview setonitemclickListener event

Tags: android, gridview

Android intent give **NullPointerException** in gridview setonitemclickListener event

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {

    GridView mGridView;
    private GridAdapter mGridAdapter;
    GridItems[] gridItems = {};
    private Activity activity;

    public GridFragment(GridItems[] gridItems, Activity activity) {
        this.gridItems = gridItems;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view;
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid, container, false);
        mGridView = (GridView) view.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        if (activity != null) {

            mGridAdapter = new GridAdapter(activity, gridItems);
            if (mGridView != null) {
                mGridView.setAdapter(mGridAdapter);
            }

             mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                 @Override
                 public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                     PackageManager pacmanager=getActivity().getPackageManager();

                     Intent i=pacmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(gridItems[position].title.toString());
                     getActivity().startActivity(i);

                 }
             });
         }
     }
```

My Error is This.

> java.lang.NullPointerException

I am getting error on line,

```
getActivity().startActivity(i);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: post the full stack trace. which is null? the activity or the intent?

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace the `getActivity().startActivity(i);`
for `MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);`

---

## quick fix

```
mGridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
      int position, long id) {
       PackageManager pacmanager=getActivity().getPackageManager();
       Intent i=pacmanager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(gridItems[position].title.toString());
        MainActivity.this.startActivity(i);

    }
   });
```

Comment: Thanks xoce but its not work, it's give me this "No enclosing instance of the type MainActivity is accessible in scope"

Comment: Ok, Thankx everybody I got my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If your intent is correct than may be your getActivity() returns null,

you can try mainactivity.startActivity(i);

YourParentActivity mainactivity;

```
@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mainActivity = (YourParentActivity ) activity;

    super.onAttach(activity);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to start `Activity` when this fragment gets attached to the Container Activity, then you have to use the `onAttach` method.

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    // use this activity
}
```

If you want to start the other activity, you can use `activity.startActivity()` and `getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);`.

Hope this helps.